# Counting a Specific value within a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have added a count line to my code to count how many times a specific value pops up and then to display it. The size of the column can vary (A huge amount)I have learnt recently a good alternative (Faster than doing an "For Each" loop) is to use the Find function but I can't see any reading material on using "Find" to count the value.

This is just a rough draft of my count code.

```
 Sub test()

     Dim rng As Range
     Dim cell As Range

        Set rng = Sheet1.Range("H2:H200")

        Count = 0

        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value = "VALUE" Then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If 
    Next cell

    Sheet1.Range("O3").Value = Count

    Count = 0

End Sub
```

can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: use pivot tables

Comment: Do you really need code for this? A simple COUNTIF formula would do the job more effectively.

Comment: I was thinking it would be easier but what I gave is just a tiny snippet of the overall Macro which will be doing a lot more than just counting a value.

Comment: Pivot table is the most efficient and easier method for this. give it a try, if you don't know how to do that using pivots, i can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Counting()

    Dim LastRow As Long, Count As Long, rng As Range, sheet1 As Worksheet

    Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("whateverursheetiscalled")
    LastRow = sheet1.Range("H2").End(xlDown).Row
    Set Range = sheet1.Range("H2:H" & LastRow)
    Count = Application.CountIf(rng, "VALUE")
    sheet1.Range("O3") = Count

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks good, is this the most effective way? as I will be doing this on about 30 different coulmns each which are around 26k long.

Comment: yeah, its just a countif... you could loop it through your columns

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a lot of data (you mention 30 columns of 26 k rows long) then as a general approach I think using arrays would be more efficient.  I applied this technique several years ago to a workbook where we applied many validations to many rows of data.  For some clients the validation routine could take up to 25 minutes.  Using Arrays, I reduced this to 4 seconds, we now use this approach everywhere unless it's very simple, limited validations/functions
The simple concept is read the whole sheet into an array, then process the array in any manner you like, then write any results back at the end.  It is all to do with the I/O between the VBA layer and the worksheet layer.  Each time you read/write a cell using VBA, there is an I/O between the application layers.  By reading the data into an array once, and writing data back at the end, you effectively reduce thousands/millions of I/O's to just 2